# Lat Long to Address

Tags: php, latitude-longitude

I am facing issue with converting latitude,longitude to adress with google api, i have to convert more than 500 latitude, longitude where as google api is limited to convert the latitude longitude to address is there any alternative to get the address from latitude longitude using PHP

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will have to use a mapping api to reverse geocode for you.
There are open source tools out there that will help you to reverse geocode, but you are better off paying google if you are getting overshot your limits.

This might be a good read on how to not use a monopoly in this field:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22816/how-to-reverse-geocode-without-google

Comment: is this possible to create own database and can i download file to store it in my local database ?